# Windows tools to diagnose dead USB ports?

Tags: windows-7, usb, hardware-failure

I have a Toshiba laptop with 3 USB ports. The ports stopped working, independently, over time.
Now I can't use a mouse with the laptop so basically it's a non functional computer for me.

I don't know if this is hardware failure or software/driver failure. It's running Windows 7 and no updates were installed recently.

Which tools can I use to troubleshoot this issue? How do I know if it's a hardware problem? 
By visual inspection I don't see any damage in the ports. Only a mouse was used in the ports.

Comment: Its a laptop...It has to have an input device built into it.

Comment: I like to use a real mouse only. Those built in ones are only good for short sessions.

Comment: I understand that.  Beyond repairing the problem yourself not sure what answer your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> I do not know if this is hardware failure or software/driver failure.

That is easy to solve. Boot another OS. If the problems go away it is a software problem.

There are quite a lot of free LiveCD's on the net. Just about any of them would do.

> Which tools can I use to troubleshoot this issue?

I would start by looking at the log files in windows. You can use windows without a mouse. It is just a little uncomfortable since most programs tend to assume mouse users, but it is possible. (E.g. use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>ESC</kbd> to open the start menu, then Cursor up to to get to the search/run menu and type  eventv. That will show the even viewer in the list of found programs. Start it with <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Alternatively, if you have configured remote desktop then you can just boot the laptop and RDP to it, using a different computer (and its keyboard and mouse).